# Scope problems when using setTimeout in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures

I am trying to toggle a state variable in my Backbone collection ("Posts") after a certain period of time (called from a view), and am trying to use setTimeout. However, I think I am screwing up my scope as my toggle function is not working (it is getting called, but it is not changing properly).

If I use

```
setTimeout(this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost, 1000);
```

, the code does not work, while if I use

```
this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost();
```

it toggles it correctly. I was wondering how I can solve this?

Backbone View

```
//ensures namespace is not already taken yet
wedding.views = wedding.views || {};

//each PostView corresponds to a single post container 
//which contains the user name, user comment, and a photo
wedding.views.PostView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: "li",
  template: "#item-template",
  className: "hideInitially post",

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.template = _.template($(this.template).html());
  },

  render: function() {
    this.preload();
    return this;
  },

  //preloads an image and only after it is done, then append
  preload: function() {
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.src = this.model.get("src");
    this.model.incrementTimesSeen();

    //hides the element initially, waits for it to finish preloading, then slides it down
    //updates lastSeen only after the image is displayed
    image.onload = $.proxy(function() {
      var html = this.template( {model: this.model.toJSON()} );

      this.model.setLastSeen();

      //shows the image by sliding down; once done, remove the hideInitially class
      this.$el.hide().append(html).slideDown();
      this.$el.removeClass("hideInitially");

      setTimeout(this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost, 1000);
    }, this);
  }

});
```

Backbone Collection

```
//check if namespace is already occupied
wedding.collections = wedding.collections || {}; 

wedding.collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: wedding.models.Post,

  initialize: function() {
    this.readyToPreloadNewPost = 1;
  },

  //toggles "readyToPreloadNewPost" between 1 and 0 
  toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost: function() {

    this.readyToPreloadNewPost = this.readyToPreloadNewPost ? 0 : 1;
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
setTimeout(this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost, 1000);
```

You're just handing `setTimeout` the plain unbound `toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost` function and `setTimeout` will call it as a simple function. The result is that `this` will be `window` inside `toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost` when `setTimeout` calls the function.

You can get the right `this` by wrapping your method call in an anonymous function:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    _this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost();
}, 1000);
```

You can also use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
setTimeout(
    _(this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost).bind(this.model.collection),
    1000
);
```

You could also use [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) inside the collection's `initialize` to always bind that method to the appropriate `this`:

```
wedding.collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost');
        //...
    }
```

And then your original

```
setTimeout(this.model.collection.toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost, 1000);
```

should do the right thing. You'd only want to go this route if you always wanted `toggleReadyToPreloadNewPost` to be bound, I'd probably go with the first one instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation! This makes so much sense!

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question: I had originally called the setTimeout within $.proxy() -> so this does not lead to the right "this" being called?

Comment: @Dan: `setTimeout($.proxy(...), 1000)` should work but `$.proxy(function() { ... setTimeout(...) })` wouldn't as the value of `this` is (usually) determined when the function is called and `setTimeout` will call it later but the `$.proxy` would only apply when you grabbed a reference to the function, not when the function was called.